# cygwin: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, configure

When trying to run ./configure in cygwin, I get the following error:

> ```
> Wayne@Wayne-PC /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14
> $ ./configure
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes
> checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
> checking for gawk... gawk
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
> checking for gcc... no
> checking for cc... no
> checking for cl.exe... cl.exe
> checking for C compiler default output file name...
> configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details.
> ```

Note that I have installed every part of cygwin but there appears to be no gcc (I thought this is included?), so I added the VS12.0 directory to #Path for cl.exe instead.

Here is the everything in config.log:

> ```
> This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
> running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.
>
> It was created by configure, which was
> generated by GNU Autoconf 2.63.  Invocation command line was
>
>   $ ./configure 
>
> ## --------- ##
> ## Platform. ##
> ## --------- ##
>
> hostname = Wayne-PC
> uname -m = i686
> uname -r = 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3)
> uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW64
> uname -v = 2014-11-13 15:45
>
> /usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
> /bin/uname -X     = unknown
>
> /bin/arch              = i686
> /usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
> /usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
> /usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
> /bin/machine           = unknown
> /usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
> /bin/universe          = unknown
>
> PATH: /usr/local/bin
> PATH: /usr/bin
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x86
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x64
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn
> PATH: /usr/bin
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin
> PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/lib
>
>
> ## ----------- ##
> ## Core tests. ##
> ## ----------- ##
>
> configure:2077: checking for a BSD-compatible install
> configure:2145: result: /usr/bin/install -c
> configure:2156: checking whether build environment is sane
> configure:2216: result: yes
> configure:2357: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
> configure:2396: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
> configure:2409: checking for gawk
> configure:2425: found /usr/bin/gawk
> configure:2436: result: gawk
> configure:2447: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
> configure:2473: result: no
> configure:2600: checking for gcc
> configure:2630: result: no
> configure:2693: checking for cc
> configure:2740: result: no
> configure:2796: checking for cl.exe
> configure:2812: found /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
> configure:2823: result: cl.exe
> configure:2859: checking for C compiler version
> configure:2867: cl.exe --version >&5
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '--version'
> cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
> configure:2871: $? = 2
> configure:2878: cl.exe -v >&5
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-v'
> cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
> configure:2882: $? = 2
> configure:2889: cl.exe -V >&5
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl : Command line error D8004 : '/V' requires an argument
> configure:2893: $? = 2
> configure:2916: checking for C compiler default output file name
> configure:2938: cl.exe    conftest.c  >&5
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> conftest.c
> Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:conftest.exe 
> conftest.obj 
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
> configure:2942: $? = 2
> configure:2980: result: 
> configure: failed program was:
> | /* confdefs.h.  */
> | #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
> | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
> | #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
> | #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
> | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
> | #define PACKAGE "Minuit2"
> | #define VERSION "5.34.14"
> | /* end confdefs.h.  */
> | 
> | int
> | main ()
> | {
> | 
> |   ;
> |   return 0;
> | }
> configure:2986: error: in `/cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14':
> configure:2989: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details.
>
> ## ---------------- ##
> ## Cache variables. ##
> ## ---------------- ##
>
> ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
> ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
> ac_cv_env_CC_set=
> ac_cv_env_CC_value=
> ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
> ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
> ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
> ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
> ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
> ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
> ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
> ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
> ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
> ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
> ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
> ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
> ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
> ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
> ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
> ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
> ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
> ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
> ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
> ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
> ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
> ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
> ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=cl.exe
> ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=no
>
> ## ----------------- ##
> ## Output variables. ##
> ## ----------------- ##
>
> ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
> ```
>
> aclocal-1.11'
>       AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
>       AMDEP_FALSE=''
>       AMDEP_TRUE=''
>       AMTAR='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
>   tar'
>       AR=''
>       AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
>   autoconf'
>       AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
>   autoheader'
>       AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
>   automake-1.11'
>       AWK='gawk'
>       CC='cl.exe'
>       CCDEPMODE=''
>       CFLAGS=''
>       CPP=''
>       CPPFLAGS=''
>       CXX=''
>       CXXCPP=''
>       CXXDEPMODE=''
>       CXXFLAGS=''
>       CXX_LIB_PATH=''
>       CYGPATH_W='cygpath -w'
>       DEFS=''
>       DEPDIR=''
>       DSYMUTIL=''
>       DUMPBIN=''
>       ECHO_C=''
>       ECHO_N='-n'
>       ECHO_T=''
>       EGREP=''
>       EXEEXT=''
>       FGREP=''
>       GMAKE=''
>       GREP=''
>       INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
>       INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
>       INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
>       INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
>       LD=''
>       LDFLAGS=''
>       LIBOBJS=''
>       LIBS=''
>       LIBSTDCPP=''
>       LIBTOOL=''
>       LIPO=''
>       LN_S=''
>       LTLIBOBJS=''
>       MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/missing --run
>   makeinfo'
>       MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
>       NM=''
>       NMEDIT=''
>       OBJDUMP=''
>       OBJEXT=''
>       OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=''
>       OTOOL64=''
>       OTOOL=''
>       PACKAGE='Minuit2'
>       PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
>       PACKAGE_NAME=''
>       PACKAGE_STRING=''
>       PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
>       PACKAGE_VERSION=''
>       PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
>       RANLIB=''
>       SED=''
>       SET_MAKE='MAKE=make'
>       SHELL='/bin/sh'
>       STRIP=''
>       VERSION='5.34.14'
>       ac_ct_CC='cl.exe'
>       ac_ct_CXX=''
>       ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
>       am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
>       am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
>       am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
>       am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
>       am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
>       am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
>       am__include=''
>       am__isrc=''
>       am__leading_dot='.'
>       am__quote=''
>       am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
>       am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
>       bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
>       build=''
>       build_alias=''
>       build_cpu=''
>       build_os=''
>       build_vendor=''
>       datadir='${datarootdir}'
>       datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
>       docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
>       dvidir='${docdir}'
>       exec_prefix='NONE'
>       host=''
>       host_alias=''
>       host_cpu=''
>       host_os=''
>       host_vendor=''
>       htmldir='${docdir}'
>       includedir='${prefix}/include'
>       infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
>       install_sh='${SHELL} /cygdrive/c/users/wayne/documents/Minuit2-5.34.14/config/install-sh'
>       libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
>       libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
>       localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
>       localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
>       lt_ECHO='echo'
>       mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
>       mkdir_p='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
>       oldincludedir='/usr/include'
>       pdfdir='${docdir}'
>       pfk_cxx_lib_path=''
>       prefix='NONE'
>       program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
>       psdir='${docdir}'
>       sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
>       sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
>       sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
>       target_alias=''
>
> ```
> ## ----------- ##
> ## confdefs.h. ##
> ## ----------- ##
>
> #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
> #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
> #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
> #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
> #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
> #define PACKAGE "Minuit2"
> #define VERSION "5.34.14"
>
> configure: exit 77
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Run the installer again and make sure you select the gcc package.  It does not come with it by default.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this from a VS command prompt?  It appears that it is the linker that is failing due to not being able to find a library.

Comment: Have run the installer multiple times with install selected on development tools, but doesn't appear to be installing gcc. Currently trying again with all packages selected. Running this in cygwin. I see that it isn't finding the library but I'm not sure why.

Comment: If it doesn't install with gcc selected by itself, I can't see how it would install if you select everything, which is extreme overkill.  You might try selecting some alternate mirrors.

Comment: Yeah, even with everything selected, it wasn't installing properly. It was a problem with the mirror. I used a different mirror and selected only development tools, it has properly installed now and configure is working. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Run the native tool from command prompt, e.g.:

[image]